# what is the difference between 'abs' function in R and sparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

in sparkR API there are functions with the same name as in R. Some of the examples are `abs,cosine` functions.

What is the difference between abs function in R and in sparkR. when does the abs function get executed in spark?

documentation for sparkR abs function
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/abs.html

Comment: I believe that [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564564/r-2-functions-with-the-same-name-in-2-different-packages) may be of interest to you since it discusses what happens when you have two packages with functions having the same name (in this case `baseR` and `sparkR`).

Answer (score 4):

The difference is where the function lives.

In base R, `abs` is a primitive:

```
function(x) .Primitive("abs")
```

In Spark, `abs` is a wrapper around a call to the Spark engine:

```
setMethod("abs",
          signature(x = "Column"),
          function(x) {
            jc <- callJStatic("org.apache.spark.sql.functions", "abs", x@jc)
            column(jc)
          })
```

You can see the R source code for the SparkR package [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/45e3be5c138d983f40f619735d60bf7eb78c9bf0/R/pkg/R/functions.R#L48).

Comment: Is there a way to get to know, where a function got executed? I mean in local R process or spark

Comment: @DesirePRG I imagine that only functions involving calls like `callJStatic` run in Spark itself, but I'm not a Spark user myself so don't quote me on it.

Answer (score 0):

In base R,it can be applied to any vector, but in SparkR, it can only be applied to columns.Suppose you have a dataframe and C3 column is double, you can use following code to add one column C4 to dataframe, which is the abs value for C3.

```
df$C4 <- abs(df$C3)
```

or

```
withColumn(df,"absvalue",abs(df&C3))
```

I think the most difference between base R and SparkR is that in SparkR, the min unit you can conduct is column, not as vector or matrix. I am just a newcomer for SparkR, I am still learning.