# Sentiment Analysis in R with tidyverse package - object 'sentiment' not found

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, tidytext

I am trying to reproduce this exmple of sentiment analysis: https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/tutorial-sentiment-analysis-in-r

I have a "file.txt" with the text I want to analyze in "../input" folder.

`library(tidyverse)`
`library(tidytext)`
`library(glue)`
`library(stringr)`
`library(dplyr)`
`require(plyr)`

`# get a list of the files in the input directory`
`files <- list.files("../input")`
`fileName <- glue("../input/", files[1], sep = "")`
`fileName <- trimws(fileName)`
`fileText <- glue(read_file(fileName))`
`fileText <- gsub("\\$", "", fileText)`
`tokens <- data_frame(text = fileText) %>% unnest_tokens(word, text)`

but after this line

```
#get the sentiment from the first text: 
tokens %>%
  inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>% # pull out only sentiment words
  count(sentiment) %>% # count the # of positive & negative words
  spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>% # made data wide rather than narrow
  mutate(sentiment = positive - negative) # # of positive words - # of negative owrds
```

I get an error message

> Error in count(., sentiment) : object 'sentiment' not found

Yesterday the same code worked fine, and today I get this error. It appears the problem is cause by `plyr` package. It seemed to work fine when `plyr` was loaded before `dplyr`, but now gives an error even if they are loaded in that order.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to receive some help, can you provide a sample data? Right now, nobody has access to your data. The bottom line is to provide a minimal reproducible data and your code. Have look of [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Meanwhile the error message is telling you that there is no column called `sentiment`. It seems that something is wrong before you used `count()`.

Comment: It is working for me. The above gives `Joining, by = "word"
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  negative positive sentiment
     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1      117      240       123`
 Have you read the data correctly?  Check the `glue` step to see if you are reading it correctly

Comment: @jazzurro Thank you for you suggestions. I edited my post to give more details. Is there anything else i need to add? @ akrun I did get the same output yesterday (i.e. negative and positive word count per document), but today it give an error. I think the have been read correctly, when i type "tokens" it gives me the first 10 tokens from the document i am trying to analyze. The next line, however, gives an error.

Comment: Can you stop here and see? `tokens %>%
  inner_join(get_sentiments("bing"))`

Comment: @Gangesh Dubey yes, this works correctly and gives me a tibble with positives and negatives. Does that mean the problem is in `count(sentiment)`? How may I be able to fix ti?

Comment: from that point onward, rest should not cause any trouble.

Comment: @Gangesh Dubey I played with code and it seems that the error disappears if I do not load `library(plyr)` package. I did not use it yesterday and that is why the code worked fine, but I added it today and if `plyr` is loaded, i get the error described above.

Comment: That makes sense, while plyr is loaded do you want to change code  to `count("sentiment")` and verify.Also please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564564/r-2-functions-with-the-same-name-in-2-different-packages) on how to force functions from a specific package

Comment: @GangeshDubey I searched the web and it seems that if I load `plyr` before `dplyr` package, I dont have the error anymore. If i follow your last recommendation, i get `Error: 'var' must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a function`. But it seems that i know how to can run the code now anyways, so thanks a lot for the promt replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by `plyr` package being loaded together with `dplyr`. I used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564564/r-2-functions-with-the-same-name-in-2-different-packages) to use `plyr` without loading it and the code runs without any errors now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error, even without loading the plyr package, you can fix it by using the explicit package when calling the "count" function:

```
dplyr::count(sentiment)
```

Alltogether it should look like this:

```
#get the sentiment from the first text: 
tokens %>%
  inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>% # pull out only sentiment words
  dplyr::count(sentiment) %>% # count the # of positive & negative words
  spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>% # made data wide rather than narrow
  mutate(sentiment = positive - negative) # # of positive words - # of negative owrds
```